# How to execute streamlit run command using subprocess

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, streamlit

I have created a streamlit app in snowflake. I am using 1.26 version of `streamlit` in `snowflake`. I have a button in my page(`main.py`) on clicking it i am opening a new page(`new_req.py`). To achive this i used `subprocess.run(["streamlit","run","new_req.py"])` in my main.py file. I am able to run this code successfully in my local. on clicking the button it is running streamlit command and opening new_req.py as a separate streamlit app. But same code when i deploy and run it in snowflake i am getting below error.

```
"PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: 'streamlit'
```

Can someone please help to solve this.